# Jest unit test breaking because of import

Tags: javascript, jestjs

So I have a file with utils:

```
import { someFunc, someOtherFunc } from 'someFile.js';

export const util1 = () => { return { abc: 1} };

export const util2 = (a, b) => { return someOtherFunc(a, b) + someFunc(a, b) };
```

Then I have another file with tests:

```
import { util1 } from 'utils.js';

describe('Whatever', () => {
  it('Does something', () => {
     const x = { a: 1 };
     const y = util1(x);

     expect(y).toEqual({ abc: 1 });
  });
});
```

As you can see I'm not importing util2, but when I run jest, it breaks the test suite. This is because of someFunc, but that function is not being used here so I don't know how to ignore it...

Answer (score 0):

1. Install

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs
```

2. Create .babelrc with

```
{
 "env": {
  "test": { 
   "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
  }
 }
}
```

3. If still does not work, try put `"type": "module"` in your package.json